# Highcharts warning: Invalid attribute 'src' in config

Tags: highcharts

Hi I started getting the warning in Title. It used to work but now it does not work anymore :(
Any tips would be greatly appreciated!
Here is a jsfiddle. When hovering mouse over one of the two dots, the error is triggered from line 204 in the JS. It should display an image: https://jsfiddle.net/yngtp9xv/

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  borderWidth: 0,
  shadow: false,
  formatter: function() {
  return '<img src="./Earthmap.jpg" width="180" height="90" />'
  },
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: OK @SebastianWędzel I have added a link to a jsfiddle. Thank you

Comment: I used another path to display the image and it seems that it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pv2hcxmk/ Are you sure that your path is correct?

Comment: I was using relative paths, but if I change to absolute path, it works. Strange. If you add an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments - it seems that there was something wrong with the image path. Changing it fixed the issue.

```
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      borderWidth: 0,
      shadow: false,
      formatter: function() {
         return '<img src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png" width="180" height="90" />'
      },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pv2hcxmk/